# Magento product detail page image not showing up

Tags: image, magento, product

I have checked the following:

- Permissions of 'media' folder (777chmod)
- Loading of media.phtml file in config.xml (The path and block type are OK)
- The base image selection by radio button in admin (all 3 checked)

Still no product detail page image showing up, while on category view is showing well. If no image is selected, in detail page no Magento logo is appearing, while this happens in category view.

Comment: is block cache enabled for your site? also, check the javascript console for any errors appearing on the product page

Comment: Is the image you are using big? such as directly from a digital camera? sometimes if you have a large image PHP can die when trying to resize the image to display :) If so resize to a sensible size before uploading.

Comment: Where can I check the block type caching? Following error is showing in JavaScript console: 

Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. acosgp91-78-rpm.html:12
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqTransform' scripts.js:82
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

@Andrew, I've also checked with a smaller image, didn't help.

Comment: Try setting the theme back to the default Magento theme and seeing if the image loads. If it does, there is most likely an issue with your custom theme.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Now I know my theme is crap. It works fine with the 'modern' theme.

Comment: After installing another theme, problem still exists. No product detail images are showing up (

Comment: I had very similar symptoms, but in my case, my PHP compile somehow missed JPEG support for GD, and conveniently, all my images were .jpg, so none showed up. Make sure that your PHP supports GD with JPEG support. You can do this by looking at the results of phpinfo()  (or php -i) and searching for JPEG Support within the GD section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the cache folder under the media/catalog/product/cache folder and refresh your page.